# while loop for overwrite result

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, python-3.7

I am writing simple code to count down and having trouble to make the time overwrite.
the result comes in as one line(as 00:00:0200:00:01) and I want it to be stacked up to look like its an actual clock

```
print(time_left,end="")
```

here is what I did and I had put `\r` as

```
print("time_left + "\r", end="")
```

which didnt work out

```
import time
while True:
    uin = input(">> ")
    try:
            when_to_stop = abs(int(uin))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
    except:
            print("Not a number!")

while when_to_stop > 0:
        m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)

           #.zfill(2) to make 00:00:00 form
        time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)
        print(time_left + '\r', + end="")
        time.sleep(1)
        when_to_stop -= 1 

print()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
print(time_left,end='\r')
```

`end='\r'` returns the cursor to the starting of the line. So when you print the same thing again it overwrites.

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment! the result came in as
00:00:03
00:00:02
00:00:01
which looks good however not exactly what I wanted
I meant to be one single line that overflows itself

Answer (score 0):

I would rework the `while` loop too (just for "beauty"). So you don´t need to use `break`. Just check if the value is not zero and set the value only if the parsing was successfull.

```
when_to_stop = 0
while(when_to_stop == 0):
    uin = input(">> ")
    try:
        when_to_stop = abs(int(uin))
    except:
        print("Not a number!")

print(when_to_stop)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use IDLE, "\r" doesn't work, you must open your program with something else or you can also double-click on your program to open it without edit, and you will see the overwrite.